# Probablity of 5 card holdem hand given 7 cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

The probabilities of getting a straight flush, 4 of a kind, full house, ... , and so on, when dealt 5 cards from a randomly shuffled deck are easily calculated as straight flush .000015, four of a kind .00024, full house .00144, ... and so on.

However, in holdem you have 7 cards with which to make your holdem hand.

Then I should expect to see the above probabilities scaled up by a factor of 21, since I now have 7 choose 5 ways in which to make my hand?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that’s wrong. The most straightforward way to see that it’s wrong is that the probabilities still have to add up to $1$. Perhaps you meant that the probability for nothing (i.e. high card) isn’t scaled up but rather decreases to make up for the increase in everything else; but that also can’t work because the probability for one pair is already more than $\frac1{21}$.

The reason this doesn’t work is that you can have various combinations in those $21$ five-card hands and only the highest one counts, but your approach assumes that all the ones that aren’t the highest (or duplicate the highest) also count.

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess I want to know what are the probabilities of drawing each of these 5 card hand types when dealt 7 random cards. I will give that calculation a shot. The background here is that I wrote a program to figure this out, but it says pairs and 2 pair hands are more probable, which is not intuitive. So, I wanted to have a way to calculate mathematically to check.

Comment: @HoberMalloy: It's all here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability#7-card_poker_hands.